It is possible to have a checked and read-only checkbox based on a condition (NOT disabled)
I'm doing management software for a travel company with PHP/Laravel.
What I want to have is as shown below:


<input type="checkbox" checked onclick="return false;" />



i.e. a checked and read-only checkbox.
So far no problem except that I have to do this only if a condition occurs, i.e. I have to have the checkbox checked and read-only only if the condition is true; in particular I must say that if the number of nights stayed is greater than 0 then the checkbox must be checked and read only, therefore it is not possible to modify it.
WARNING: I DO NOT want the checkbox disabled
I tried to do as shown in the following code, but only the checked works.


<input type="checkbox" {{$client->stay_night > 0 ? 'checked' : ''}} {{$client->stay_night > 0 && 'onclick="return false;"'}} />



Can anyone help me do this? I would be very grateful!

Have you tried : <input type="checkbox" {{$client->stay_night > 0 ? 'checked' : ''}} {{$client->stay_night > 0 ? 'onclick="return false;"' : '' }} />

@Mohammadsiabbou Yes, I tried that too. They don't seem to like onclick written that way

It is working in that way, right ?

@Mohammadsiabbou no it doesn't work, only the checked works

Sorry i think i know the issue now , Laravel escapes html so it wouldn't work , you have to do it like this to skip that : <input type="checkbox" {{$client->stay_night > 0 ? 'checked' : ''}} {!! $client->stay_night > 0 ? 'onclick="return false;"' : '' !!} />

You can use @if($client->stay_night > 0)....@endif. Keep in mind that everyone can tamper with the checkbox on the browser side so I recommend ignoring the value received from the checkbox and checking the condition on the backend side. At this point it is irrilevant whether the checkbock is disabled or not.
